# How much is the overhead of network traffic when I use SELECT FOR XML to transfer 5000 records

Tags: sql-server

My C# application needs to transform batches of 5000 records of SQL server data into XML files every hour.

A very easy option is to use SELECT FOR XML and transform SQL server records on the server then get the XML data through the network.

I am concern about the extra load on the SQL server and the network traffic overhead since XML data is much bigger than SQL server tabular data.

Is my concern valid?

1. Does FOR XML transformation consumes lots of SQL server resources?
2. Does SQL Client transfers XML data as plain text or it has a more
       efficient mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select Raw Xml the performance will be better than Auto Xml , but sure it will be less performance  than select  tabular data.

We run a benchmark for the three cases and measure time of execution in the client  and rows /second.

These values depends on the server performance (memory , cpu, disk io speed) and  network speed.

**Lab Environment:**

```
 SQL Server: 64bit /16G Byte /windows 7
 The client: x86 (32 bit) , memory 2GB /windows 7
 Network Cards for both: 1Gb per second
```

For the database Adventureworks2012, table [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]   has row number: 121317

The sql statement that will be executed in the client are:

```
 Tabular data: select *  FROM Sales.[SalesOrderDetail]
 Raw Xml     : select *  FROM Sales.[SalesOrderDetail] FOR XML RAW 
 Auto Xml    : select *  FROM Sales.[SalesOrderDetail] FOR XML AUTO
```

The following table show the execution time in the three cases for selecting 121317 row:

```
  Mode     Time[Sec]    Row_per_second
  tabular   0.41        298810
  Raw Xml   1.11        109492
  AutoXml   5.61        21621

 application: Dotnet 4.5 , sqlclient
```

The following figures show Bar chart for time and rows_per_second:

[image: Rows per second]

Figure (1): Rows per second

[image]

Figure (2): Retrieval time in second

**Conclusion:**

the Tabular data is best performance than Raw Xml than Auto Xml.
The performanane depends on row size, server /client performance (memory, cpu) and network speed.

For your data size of 5000 row the difference in time is small and may be fractional part of seconds.

**Update:**

**Does FOR XML transformation consumes lots of SQL server resources?**

XML data type  is implemented as CLR data types. In general, the CLR in SQL server is faster than T-SQL UDFs and TVFs (to varying degrees).

**Reference:** [CLR Performance Testing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-performance-testing/?__hstc=99199553.bc6aaf98356c4acea3e305e017d98477.1469039088425.1472992764919.1473597004507.16&__hssc=99199553.1.1473597004507&__hsfp=3344649653)

The main overhead of XML conversion is the size of xml data in the different mode (Raw Xml is compact size using Attributes while Auto xml largeer size using Elements) over the network from server to the client compared to the size of tabular data.

The server resource overhead is minor and can be neglected.
So, xml stream is mainly a network resource overhead.

**Does SQL Client transfers XML data as plain text or it has a more efficient mechanism?**

XML data is transferred as a plain TEXT UTF-16 (all string data type in DOT-NET are UTF-16)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the elaborative answer. Do you know how heavy is the network overhead? Is XML data being transferred as binary or text to the client?

Comment: Xml data are transferred as text (string UTF-16)

Comment: If the data is transferred as text, it imposes a big overhead.

Comment: @Allan,yes, it's a network  overhead based on the size of data and the speed of network and its effect is shown in rows_per_sec graph for both raw and auto xml mode .You can monitor the xml stream as a text using a network monitoring tool. Review a captured frame of my data with length 1460 byte: https://imgur.com/a/kZCli 
Note the string <row SalesOrderID="43659" in UTF-16 (Unicode)